# Showing two things are homotopic to each other

Tags: homotopy-theory

I want to show that $\mathbb{C} - \{0\} \simeq S^1$ and the unit square is $\simeq S^1$ where $\simeq$ is homotopic in this case. In other words I want to find an equation for each sort of speak that defines a unit square with one value and a circle for another value. I have done this before with the annulus and the circle by letting $H(z,t) = (1-t)z + \displaystyle\frac{z}{|z|}$. I want to do something similar for the other two examples I brought up. The help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please be more precise. (i) When you say "unit square", do you mean the *border* of a unit square? (ii) When you say "homotopic", do you actually mean "homotopic maps", or do you mean "homotopy equivalent spaces"?

Comment: I mean the border of a unit square

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to show that $I^2$ (the unit square, where $I=[0,1]$) is homotopy equivalent to $S^1$ because that's not true.

To show that $\mathbb C-\{0\}$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^1$, it suffices to find a deformation retraction of $\mathbb C-\{0\}$ onto $S^1$. Here's one way to do that: for each point $z\in\mathbb C-\{0\}$, the point on $S^1$ which is closest to $z$ is $z/|z|$. Make the deformation retraction by sending $z$ to $z/|z|$ at constant speed along the line connecting them. (Draw a picture if you don't understand!) Points that are farther away will have to move more quickly. Can you find the formula for this deformation retraction?

Edit: The border of the unit square (call it $X$) is homotopy equivalent to $S^1$. You can show it by making a straight-line homotopy (along the lines of the other part of this question) from $1_X$ to $1_{S^1}$. That is, connect each point of $X$ with the corresponding point on the unit circle (what do I mean by corresponding point?) and move it along the line connecting them.

Comment: Would it be $H(z,t) = (1-t)z + t \displaystyle\frac{z}{|z|}$? Also, I think the first one can work since I only mean the border of the square.

Comment: Looks good to me. See my edit for the other bit.

Comment: Okay so I was a little lost as to understanding what you were saying for the border of a square and a circle but based off of what I did understand would my equation be of the form $H(x,t) = (1-t)f(x) + tg(x)$ still?

Comment: Yeah, that's right. Sorry for the brevity. I highly recommend drawing pictures to understand what's going on.

Comment: Oh I completely understand. I have been drawing pictures for these. I thought about taking a circle inscribed in a square and then considering the radius of that circle. At least that is what I drew. I am a little lost as to exactly what my $H(x,t)$ should be though.

Comment: Good! So in general, the easiest way to make a homotopy between two $\mathbb R^n$- or $\mathbb C$-valued functions $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is to use $H(x,t)=(1-t)\alpha(x)+t\beta(x)$, which I call a "straight-line homotopy" because it corresponds to drawing lines between the curves. This won't always work -- for example, if the homotopy moves "outside" of the allowed space -- but is usually a good first guess.

Comment: About the last paragraph: haw can we even talk about a homotopy between $1_X$ and $1_{S^1}$? You can have a homotopy between two maps $f, g: A \to B$. But in your case $1_X$ is $X \to X$, and $1_{S^1}$ is $S^1 \to S^1$. It doesn't make sense to call these two maps homotopic.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. That's nonsense! I have to run off, but I'll fix it later. I think the OP was confused about the difference between "homotopic" and "homotopy equivalent" and I let some of the confusion rub off on me.